# Subtract BigDecimal without Rounding up

Tags: java

I have a function that receives two BigDecimal numbers say bd1 and bd2 as paramters. The function should subtract bd1 - db2 and return

Scale of bd1 and bd2 is both 2 and the result should also have scale of 2 only
But using subtract is scaling out to full decimal representation
I want  the scale set at 2 and tried using setScale , but setScale is expeccting 
a roundingmode and unclear on which rounding mode to use to get exact result limited to scale 2

The need is to get the exact subtracted value (bd1 - bd2)  with scale of 2 .
In this case i need 15.04 without rounding as am getting these value from another application and i dont want to change the values by adding Rounding mode

```
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(30.18);
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(15.14);

    BigDecimal diff =  bd1.subtract(bd2);
    System.out.println("bd1.subtract(bd2)       " + diff);   

    System.out.println("RoundingMode.DOWN       " + diff.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN));
    System.out.println("RoundingMode.FLOOR      "  + diff.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR));

    System.out.println("RoundingMode.UP         " +diff.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP));

    System.out.println("RoundingMode.CEILING    " + diff.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));

    System.out.println("RoundingMode.HALF_UP    " + diff.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));



Result
------
bd1.subtract(bd2)       15.03999999999999914734871708787977695465087890625
RoundingMode.DOWN       15.03
RoundingMode.FLOOR      15.03
RoundingMode.UP         15.04
RoundingMode.CEILING    15.04
RoundingMode.HALF_UP    15.04
```

Actual result is 15.04

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing `BigDecimal` using a `double`, so it won't have enough precision. Use `String` as parameter for the constructor instead:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("30.18");
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("15.14");

BigDecimal diff =  bd1.subtract(bd2);
System.out.println("bd1.subtract(bd2)  " + diff);
```

Comment: thanks, am receiving  it as a BigDecimal values from another object .

Comment: senderObj.bd1, senderObj.bd2 --> Both are BigDecimal

Comment: How to get the String form of it and do the subtract s you suggested. Tried toString and toPlainString() on bd1  both are converting to 30.17999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875

Comment: `bd1 = bd1.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);` (same for bd2) before you do the calculation. And tell the person who wrote the code that's calling you, not to convert doubles to BigDecimal but to work with BigDecimal all the way - otherwise there is no point.

Comment: BigDecimal diff =  bd3.subtract(bd4);

Comment: diff.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)..... is it safe to round up after subtracting . I know for sure bd1 and bd2 both have scale of 2 when i receive them

Comment: @delashungry my answer means that you should initialize your instances of `BigDecimal` using a String. How are they initialized, where their values come from?